# Select inner faces and select non-manifold geometry not working

Tags: faces, geometry

Often times when I build a model, I will join 2 objects together, creating inner faces that tend to screw up my armature weights. I researched various ways to select this interior geometry but none of them appear to work. I tried these methods on a complex model as well as on a simple set of cubes. In any case, nothing gets selected and there is no error code.[image]

Comment: Can you state the "various ways" you have tried.
Obviously the boolean modifier is one approach, but it has it's drawbacks. Have you tried using the Intersect (boolean) tool in edit mode?

Comment: The Boolean modifier did help me figure stuff out. Thank you.